# Need to round dollar value up to next nickel

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Can someone give me an example of rounding a dollar value to the next highest nickel?  For example:  If my amount is 21.402, I need it to be 21.45, not 21.40.  I have it currently rounding to the **NEAREST** nickel which would gives me 21.40 in this case.  I need it to round to .45.

**Edit** Code:

```
 C                   Eval      Work=0
 C                   Eval      RMD=0
 C     Price         DIV       .05           Work
 C                   MVR                     RMD
 C                   If        RMD > 0
 C                   Eval      Price = (Work * .05) + .05
 C                   EndIf
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you tried.

Comment: C                   Eval      Work=0                          
 C                   Eval      RMD=0                           
 C     Price         DIV       .05           Work              
 C                   MVR                     RMD               
 C                   If        RMD > 0                         
 C                   Eval      Price = (Work * .05) + .05      
 C                   EndIf

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the (unspecified) definitions of the `WORK` field.  MVR will return the remainder - the number of nickels left over after the division.  If there's a fractional result of the division, there won't be a remainder.  If the fields are defined:

```
 d work            s              9p 2
 d rmd             s             15p 6
 d price           s              7p 3 inz(21.402)
```

then

```
 C     Price         DIV       .05           Work
```

puts 428.04 in `WORK` and there is no remainder - the full result is stored in `WORK`.  If the fields are defined:

```
 d work            s              9p 0
 d rmd             s             15p 6
 d price           s              7p 3 inz(21.402)
```

then

```
 C     Price         DIV       .05           Work
```

puts 428 in `WORK` and there is a remainder of .002

Comment: Thank you!  Was all in how I had the remainder defined.  Much Appreciated!!